# Editions of Gur Aryeh by the Maharal

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, maharal

I am looking for a good edition of Gur Aryeh by the Maharal. I am aware of these editions -

https://www.machon-y.com/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94/

https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/chumash-gur-aryeh-hashalem-5-volume-set/45011

https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/chumash-gur-aryeh-2-volume-set/45024

Which one of these editions would you recommend? Are there others aside from these that are worth checking out?

I am looking for an edition that is - a) accurate and error free b) all-Hebrew c) with clear, nice print, and d) shelf friendly (does not take up many volumes)

The Machon Yerushalaim edition looks fantastic, but it also has a lot of notes and takes up nine volumes...

Comment: I was very happy with this edition - https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/chumash-gur-aryeh-2-volume-set/45024

Answer (score 2):

There is a publisher called Tiferes (they publish all of the Maharal's seforim, they're black and electric-blue). They make two versions of the Gur Aryeh, one is just the plain text of the Gur Aryeh with nothing fancy, it's in two volumes (it's the one brought in @pcoz comment). They also make a five volume edition with chumash, Rashi, and Onkelos and the Gur Aryeh on the bottom. The tiferes has very nice print which is very easy to read. The two volume one (and obviously the five volume one, being that it's a normal chumash) also has the parsha, perek and pasuk on the top of each page which makes it very easy to reference.

If you can manage to find them, there is also the very old printing of the sifrei Maharal (they're brownish/yellowish, thin volumes, and they all just say "sifrei maharal" on the spine) which if I remember correctly is also just the plain text of the Gur Aryeh. These are the "classic" printing of the sifrei maharal (if you see someone quoting a sefer of the Maharal with a page number (which I know the "Mesoras HaShas" Ein Yaakov does), it's probably this printing.)

I can't say the accuracy of either of these girsa'os is *bad*, but I can say that Rabbi Hartman's edition from Mechon Yerushalayim certainly has a better one and even brings alternative girsa'os in his footnotes. It's worth mentioning that the ninth volume in Rabbi Hartman's edition (which is the thickest volume) is just a mafte'ach, and you could probably keep it not on your shelf. [Rabbi Hartman's text is the one used in Me'oros Hagedolim/Otzar Meforshei Rashi (the set of chumashim with eleven, yes eleven meforshei Rashi, it is seven volumes, highly recommended).] Another point about this edition, the footnotes are really, really good. They are not just page fillers, they help explain many of the concepts that the Maharal speaks about by bringing his explanations of the same ideas elsewhere. Rabbi Hartman is a tremendous buckey in the sifrei Maharal.